# Is it ok to split classes in multiple header files?

Tags: c++

I've got a class that consists of a few functions and a lot of operators. Almost all functions and operators use templates which is why I've implemented them in the header file. 
This made it pretty hard to find something in the code so I decided to move all operators into a seperate headerfile.

now I have something like:

fstring.h

```
class fstring{
    ...
    #include "fstring_operators.h"
}
```

and fstring_operators.h

```
...
template<int RSIZE>
bool operator==(const fstring<RSIZE>& rhs) const {
    return equals(rhs._chars, RSIZE);
}
...
```

Is it ok to do something like this? I've also omitted header guards for fstring_operators.h because it must not be included anywhere except in fstring.h

Comment: It's definitely possible, but may make it harder to understand your class without proper documentation. For example it won't be easy to just scan the class declaration to see if it has some special method or operator.

Comment: I don't know if it is a "best practice", but I think it's ok and may help in keeping code cleaner. Though, as a general rule and not looking at a specific case, if you need it too much, it could mean that the design of your class(es) can be made better.

Comment: One option is to just declare the member functions inside the class definition, and then define them afterwards (either in the same header, or another one). That would make it easier to find the definition, without having to jump to a different file, and without introducing files that can only be included in special places.

Comment: Look at boost::facade, and also look at CRTP. Both offer solutions here. I'd personally use macros rather than includes, but this is personal taste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I've seen this in production code before, I don't really agree with this style for 2 reasons:

1) You expect a `class` to be fully defined in the header. You shouldn't need to look inside other headers to find what you're looking for.

2) You can include the other header elsewhere. Even without include guards, it's not a guarantee it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should define the methods as free functions.  Then you can #include  at the bottom of your regular header file, which is a practice that many C++ libraries use (some of them would make the operators filename end with .i or .inl or something).

If you do it that way it seems fine.  The way you wrote in the OP is a little stranger, and even if it works, may throw off some maintainers of your code, and possibly even some development tools.